# Entity Framework doesn't save children on edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a controller action which saves data to db on change. Model includes children Files, they are not saved to the database however. Data comes ok from the server, file is added to the model from the request ok, but it just won't save. There is no error occuring.

These are my models:

```
 public class Guest
{
    public Guest()
    {
        this.Files = new List<File>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int Votes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<File> Files {get; set;}
}
```

This is my VM

```
public class GuestViewModel
{
    public Guest Guest { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit( GuestViewModel guestViewModel, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {

        if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var avatar = new File
            {
                FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName),
                FileType = FileType.Picture,
                ContentType = upload.ContentType
            };
            using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
            {
                avatar.Content = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
            }
            guestViewModel.Guest.Files = new List<File> { avatar };
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

                Guest guest = new Guest();
                guest = guestViewModel.Guest;
                _db.Entry(guest).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        return View(guestViewModel);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to set the state for the child entities too, because when you attach an entity to a context setting the state directly, any child entities is attacched in "unchanged" state, so is ignored in save changes.

In this case, the state that you need to use for child files is Added.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, yes. It helps if I state '_db.Entry(guest).State = EntityState.Modified;' right after I added the the file to model it is saved. However if I want to change the current file and therfore assign EntityState.Modified it results in error on '_db.SaveChanges();' stating I have modified (0) rows. Do you know how to overcome this?